# I am trying to get the API from another module everything is corrects i dont know why i am getting this error?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

```
# import the requests library
import requests

# import the API key
from config import weather_api_key



Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/Users/siddhantarora/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 3437, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)

  File "<ipython-input-7-2ca4475f6397>", line 5, in <module>
    from config import weather_api_key

  File "/Users/siddhantarora/Desktop/BOOTCAMP/World_Weather_Analysis/config.py", line 1
    weather_api_key = 5cdc2fee9307ead10a4b44367c7aec48
                       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: probably you forgot quotation marks around the key: `weather_api_key = "5cdc2fee9307ead10a4b44367c7aec48"`

Comment: And if that's your actual API key, then you need to delete it and create another one, because everyone in the world knows your key now.

Answer (score 1):

in the file `/Users/siddhantarora/Desktop/BOOTCAMP/World_Weather_Analysis/config.py` you have to change `weather_api_key = 5cdc2fee9307ead10a4b44367c7aec48` to `weather_api_key = "5cdc2fee9307ead10a4b44367c7aec48"` with quotes.

You should also change your api key if this is a real one because anyone can steal it.